# Way to close child HTA file if it gets called again from a parent HTA file

Tags: vbscript, hta, tasklist

I want to run a HTA file where, there is a loop in which the parent HTA calls a child HTA to display an update on a regular interval. I want the child HTA to be remain open with old update and it should close when it is called again with new update and diplay it. I tried to do it, but I am unable to add close HTA condition on the child HTA. Which results in all Child HTA opened in the background.

Parent HTA File,

Code given below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent Application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Parent Application"
  ID="ParentApplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub OnClickButtonConnect()
  Dim currentDirectory,pos
  pos=InStrRev(document.location.pathname,"\")
  currentDirectory=""
  If pos>0 Then
    currentDirectory = Left(document.location.pathname,pos)
  End If

  Dim WshShell, i, g
  g = 5
  set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
  For i = 1 To g
  cmdline = "mshta.exe """ & currentDirectory & "child.hta"" """ & login.value & """ """ & password.Value & """"
  WshShell.Run cmdline,1,False
  next
  window.close
End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="white">

<!--Add your controls here-->

Login:<input type="text" name="login" id="login"><BR>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><BR>
<input type="button" name="Connect" id="Connect" value="Connect" onclick="OnClickButtonConnect">
<!--{{InsertControlsHere}}-Do not remove this line-->
</body>
</html>
```

Child HTA

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Child Application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Child Application"
  ID="ChildApplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
  str=""
  arguments = Split(ChildApplication.CommandLine," """)
  For i=0 To UBound(arguments)
    arguments(i)=Replace(arguments(i),"""","")
  Next
  document.body.innerhtml="login is: " & arguments(1) & "<BR>password is: " &  arguments(2)
End Sub

</script>

<body bgcolor="white">

<!--Add your controls here-->

<!--{{InsertControlsHere}}-Do not remove this line-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any one to help please

Comment: Try to edit your question and post your HTA code !

Comment: Can you put the command line to the child HTA in your WMI query that selects processes to close? `Select * from Win32_Process where CommandLine like '%child.hta%'`

Comment: @Hackoo I have added the HTA code

Comment: @langstrom looking for child HTA to get closed when it is called again with new input.

Comment: Any one to help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this Sub before opening the child hta. Make sure the name of the hta matches its actual name.

```
Sub CloseChild
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select CommandLine from Win32_Process where CommandLine like '%child.hta%'")
    For Each objProcess In colProcessList
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next 
End Sub
```

Edit: I just wanted to comment for anyone who may read this later. Putting `CommandLine` in the select statement is not explicitly required, even though this property is used in the `where` clause. You can select any or all of the properties in the [Win32_Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, including *or excluding* `CommandLine`.

I do suggest selecting only the properties you need to increase the speed of the query, and historically, for clarity, I select the same property as I use in the `where` clause if I don't actually *need* one.